# How to Logout (Go to Base URL) if local Storage doesn't have certain key-value pair in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am implementing a simple logout functionality if my local storage doesn't have a particular key-value pair and if the value is empty or if the 'token' inside the value is expired.

My current Code: TokenExpired.js

```
import { isExpired } from "react-jwt";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const VerifyAccessToken = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const Data = localStorage.getItem('Admin Credentials')
    const existanceOfData = Data !== null

    if (existanceOfData) {
        if (Data && Data !== 'undefined') {
            const tokenExpired = isExpired(JSON.parse(Data).accessToken);
            if (tokenExpired) {
                localStorage.removeItem("Admin Credentials");
                navigate('/')
            }
        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem("Admin Credentials");
            navigate('/')
        }
    } else {
        navigate('/')
    }

}
```

I am using this in My Dashboard Page : Dashboard/Dashboard/js

```
import "./Dashboard.scss";
import { adminAuth } from "../../helpers/AdminInformation";
import { VerifyAccessToken } from "../../helpers/TokenExpired";

// components ---------------------------------
certain components

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Dashboard = () => {
    const [dashboard, setDashboard] = useState({ received: 0, expected: 0 })
    const token = adminAuth.accessToken;
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(baseURL + 'api/dashboard/', {
            headers: {
                token: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(json => setDashboard(json));
    }, [token])

    VerifyAccessToken();

    return (
        <div className="dashboard">
            content
        </div>
    );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Whenever I try to delete that key value after logging in, it shows error:
[image]

Comment: It looks like the error/stacktrace is blaming something a `List` component from a `Table.js` file. Can you edit the post to include the error message and stacktrace as a properly formatted and readable text/code snippet? This will likely mean including all the relevant code in the stacktrace as part of your [mcve].

Comment: What is `VerifyAccessToken` supposed to be? It's named like a React component but doesn't return any JSX, and called like a React hook, which breaks the rules of hooks by calling other React hooks (i.e. can't call hooks from nested functions).

Answer (score 0):

I Found the Answer to my Question:

I figured I need to make my Routes Strong so that there are no warning about my routes in the console

I Created Layout Component for my Dashboard Page & Update Token Expired Code with useEffect(), It worked...

My Updated Code: TokenExpired.js

```
import { isExpired } from "react-jwt";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const VerifyAccessToken = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const Data = localStorage.getItem('Admin Credentials')
    const existanceOfData = Data !== null

    useEffect(() => {
        if (existanceOfData) {
            if (Data && Data !== 'undefined') {
                const tokenExpired = isExpired(JSON.parse(Data).accessToken);
                if (tokenExpired) {
                    navigate('/')
                }
            } else {
                navigate('/')
            }
        } else {
            navigate('/')
        }
    }, [Data, existanceOfData, navigate]);
}
```